# Sextante Modeler Error "global name os is not defined"

Tags: qgis, python, error, sextante

I want to generate a model whic reclassify radter values. So i added Saga reclassify grid values tool to Modeler and saved the model. When i run the model i got this error both on Ubuntu OSgeolive 6.0 and Win7. **But this tool runs succesfully directly in Qgis. the error occur when i want to run in Modeler.** I use Qgis 1.8.0 and Sextante 1.0.9. I need your help...

[image]